Local atlas deployment raise "Get "https://production.cloudflare.docker.com ... dial tcp 157.240.10.36:443: i/o timeout" error
I use atlas deployments setup for local atlas devlopment,
It shows the following message:
Creating your cluster local6606 [this might take several minutes]

1/3: Starting your local environment…
2/3: Downloading the MongoDB binaries to your local environment…
Error: exit status 125: Error: copying system image from manifest list: parsing image configuration: Get "https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e0/e00840108d90158e8fc399e96cc40c2979edc578f20406e2720ee60fd67ca9e8/data?verify=1720276469-uFisRAoQerXj8vPKnx49VOkfiOI%3D": dial tcp 31.13.94.36:443:: dial tcp 157.240.10.36:443: i/o timeout

It seems the https://production.cloudflare.docker.com network access from my mac has some issue. Is there any way to mirror the atlas container registries or other solution for this?
